# jQuery pushStack

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack

I need some help to understand `pushStack`

Here I've made an example where the results using it or not are the same http://jsfiddle.net/Bz5n9/2/ so I think i really didn't get what is it for.

Thanks!

Comment: Shoud "jquery-stack" tag be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently adding to the collection, pushing a new collection on the stack that's already the result (you could just return the result of `this.add()`).  What this does is instead of pushing `.b` elements on the stack as a new element, it pushes a new set with `.b` elements *and* the `#2` `<li>` you started with.

Instead, you instead should pass the elements directly (no [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) call), like this:

```
return this.pushStack(newCollection, "agregate", "");
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Bz5n9/3/).

Comment: In your example the codes behave differente because they realy do different things and not because they use or not pushStack, but still you helped me to create a good example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bz5n9/4/

Comment: @Diego - perhaps I'm misunderstanding...what do you *want* to happen, and what's breaking your expectations? If it helps, in your second example what's happening is that since you're returning `newCollection`, it has no `.prevObject` set, so `.end()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I just wanted to see the difference between using and not using pushStack. In my example I could actually see it. In your example the difference was because in the first case you use an add, and in the second place you "changed" the collection to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Ben does a good job of explaining it here:

[http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1739-Using-PushStack-In-jQuery-Plugins-To-Create-
New-Collections.htm](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1739-Using-PushStack-In-jQuery-Plugins-To-Create-New-Collections.htm)