# How does the jQuery pushStack function work?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble understanding the jQuery pushStack function (documented at http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/). I have tried to add a list of items to a selector in this Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnhoffman/hTh8D/

JS:

```
$(function() {
   var listStuff = $("p");
   listStuff.pushStack($("div"));
   listStuff.css("color", "#f00");        
});​
```

HTML:

```
<p>foo</p>
<div>bar</div>​
```

However, the text of the div element is not red. What does it mean to push an element onto a jQuery stack?

Comment: Although vague, it is concise (as is the example). Push **DOM** elements in to the stack, not jQuery-wrapped elements.

Comment: Thank you, what is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery pushStack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399055/jquery-pushstack)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.pushStack()` creates a new jQuery object that inherits state from a previous jQuery object.

This inherited state allows methods like `.end()` and `.self()` to work properly.  In your particular code example, you aren't using the return value from `.pushStack()` which is the new jQuery object.

When working with jQuery objects, it's important to know that most operations that change what DOM objects are in a jQuery object return a new jQuery object with the change in it rather than modifying the existing jQuery object.  It is this design characteristic that allows them to maintain this stack of previously modified jQuery objects.

In your case, I don't think you need to use `.pushStack()` at all and you can probably just use `.add()` (which also returns a new jQuery object) but it isn't exactly clear to me what you're trying to do so I'm not sure exactly what code to recommend.

To achieve the end result HTML you showed in your question, you could do this:

```
$(function() {
   $("p").add("div").css("color", "#f00").appendTo(document.body);        
});​
```

You could obviously change the `.appendTo()` to whatever you intend to do with the new DOM objects.

In your comments you asked some more about when one would use `pushStack()`.  I think the main use is in jQuery methods that return a new jQuery object.  In that case, you create the new list of elements you want in the new jQuery object and then rather than just turning that into a regular jQuery object and returning it, you call `return this.pushStack(elems)`.  This ends up creating a new jQuery object and returning it, but it also links that new object to the previous object so that special commands like `.end()` can work when used in chaining.

The jQuery `.add()` method is a classic example.  In pseudo-code, what it does is this:

```
add: function(selector, context) {
    // get the DOM elements that correspond to the new selector (the ones to be added)
    // get the DOM elements from the current jQuery object with this.get()
    // merge the two arrays of elements together into one array
    return this.pushStack(combinedElems);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That make sense. My end was to just figure out how to use pushStack. Is there a corresponding "begin()" function then - or is pushStack essentially the function that begins a new say "frame" in the stack? I couldn't find one anywhere.

Comment: @JohnHoffman - `pushStack()` is like `begin()`.  It creates a new jQuery object that is linked to the previous one.  You don't have to use `pushStack()`, you can just create a new jQuery object, but using `pushStack()` lets the commands like `.end()` work because of knowledge of the previously the linked versions.  It's a pretty advanced usage pattern that is not required for normal jQuery usage.

Comment: @JohnHoffman - `pushStack()` makes more sense with chaining when you are returning a jQuery object from within a jQuery method, thus it's typically used in the internal implementation of jQuery methods or when creating new jQuery methods that result in a new jQuery object.  I've never seen it used outside of a jQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing the object, try this :

```
$(function() {
var listStuff = $("p");
listStuff.css("color", "#f00");        
this.pushStack( listStuff.get() );
});​
```