# Difference between jquery pushStack and add method

Tags: jquery

`.add():`
**Description**: Add elements to the set of matched elements.

`.pushStack():` **Description:** Add a collection of DOM elements onto the jQuery stack.

I'm having trouble understanding the jQuery pushStack function .Are `add()` and `pushStack()` method similar in functionality?

.pushStack() creates a new jQuery object that inherits state from a previous jQuery object.What does that state mean?

Comment: Please see this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197753/how-does-the-jquery-pushstack-function-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily understand difference b/w `.add()` and `.pushStack()` -

For `.add()` - 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VUKMc/)

By using `.add()` method we can `Add elements` into current Object.

For  `.pushStack()` - 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PrtWm/2/)

By using `.pushStack()` method we can `Add a New DOM Object element`.