# What is jquery stack?

Tags: jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the jQuery pushStack function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197753/how-does-the-jquery-pushstack-function-work)

In the jQuery API I saw a function `pushStack`. The description sais: `Add a collection of DOM elements onto the jQuery stack.`

Does anyone know wat the jQuery stack is and for what can it be used? Does it has a relation with the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chain multiple jQuery methods together and each method returns a new jQuery object, jQuery keeps track of all the jQuery objects in a stack.  This allows you to return to a previously used jQuery object without having to save it in a local variable.  To make this work, when a jQuery method creates a new jQuery object as a result of a method call, it calls `pushStack()` to allow the new object to participate in the stack.

The jQuery method `.end()` is somewhat the reverse of `.pushStack()` in that it goes one item back in the stack to get the prior jQuery object and it can be called multiple times to continue going back in the stack.  See [the `.end()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/end/) for more info.

For an example of using `.pushStack()`, let's say you wanted a method that would get all text nodes in a container, you could do so like this and return the new resulting jQuery object using `.pushStack()`:

```
jQuery.fn.textNodes = function() {
    var nodes = [];
    this.each(function() {
        var node = this.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                nodes.push(node);
            }
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    });
    return this.pushStack(nodes, "textNodes");
};
```

Comment: Fantastic example and spot-on explanation, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Most of jQuery's DOM traversal methods operate on a jQuery object instance and produce a new one, matching a different set of DOM elements. When this happens, it is as if the new set of elements is pushed onto a stack that is maintained inside the object. Each successive filtering method pushes a new element set onto the stack. You have different function to operate directly on this stack such as:

- [pushStack](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/)
- [end](http://api.jquery.com/end/)
- [andSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jQuery source [line 203 of core.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L203), the stack refers to the current set of elements in the jQuery object instance. Think of it like chaining.. when you filter you are adding to the stack. Calling end() will pop that set and return to the previous set in the stack. `.pushStack()` allows you to add a new set of elements to this stack.

```
// Take an array of elements and push it onto the stack
// (returning the new matched element set)
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {

    // Build a new jQuery matched element set
    var ret = jQuery.merge( this.constructor(), elems );

    // Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
    ret.prevObject = this;

    ret.context = this.context;

    if ( name === "find" ) {
        ret.selector = this.selector + ( this.selector ? " " : "" ) + selector;
    } else if ( name ) {
        ret.selector = this.selector + "." + name + "(" + selector + ")";
    }

    // Return the newly-formed element set
    return ret;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with .end()

See: 
[jQuery pushStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399055/jquery-pushstack)

also: 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1739-Using-PushStack-In-jQuery-Plugins-To-Create-New-Collections.htm