# Adding DOM elements to jQuery stack array

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a selector that gets a couple of items, and I want to add an element to that stack. Is this not what [pushStack](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/) is for?

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="color-me">Line 1</div>
    <div class="color-me">Line 2</div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var $divs = $('.color-me');

var $generatedDiv = $('<div></div>', {
    'class': 'color-me',
    'text': 'Line 3'
}).appendTo($('#container'));

$divs.pushStack($generatedDiv);

// Shouldn't the $generatedDiv be in the $divs jQuery stack now?
$divs.css('color', 'red');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bGDxw/

Comment: In your instance, I think you're looking `add()`.

Comment: I believe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399055/jquery-pushstack

Comment: I also like http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197824/68146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is .add(). Instead of

```
$divs.pushStack($generatedDiv);
```

Try

```
$divs = $divs.add($generatedDiv);
```

Answer (score 2):

`pushStack` does indeed add them to the jQuery stack, but that's not what you're dealing with there. You're dealing with an array of jQuery objects.

As a result, you need to use the [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function:

> **Description:** *Add elements to the set of matched elements.*

For example:

```
var $divs = $('.color-me');

var $generatedDiv = $('<div />', {
    'class': 'color-me',
    'text': 'Line 3'
}).appendTo($('#container'));

$divs = $divs.add($generatedDiv);
$divs.css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: .add() returns a new collection. You'll need to do $divs = $divs.add($generatedDiv)

Comment: @BenM My bad. I must have been looking at the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$divs.add($generatedDiv);`

See [jQuery.add() function](http://api.jquery.com/add/) documentation.